# Mongoose set text index for a field

Tags: mongoose

I have schema like this :

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
          title:  String,
          body: String,
          path: String
        });
```

I want add text index to title field.

I used this code :

```
mySchema.index({title: 'text'});
```

But it's not working , i be appreciated if tell me where i am  wrong.

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you running ?

Comment: @TomToms  mongoose@4.0.1

Comment: Code looks ok.  What's not working about it?

Comment: @JohnnyHK problem is its not create text index for title , mongodb give this error `error: {
        "$err" : "Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=music.artists limit=0 skip=0\nTree: TEXT : query=test, language=, tag=NULL\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: need exactly one text index for $text query",
        "code" : 17007
}
` i have to create index manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can add text index like this

```
ModelSchema.index({ '$**': 'text' }) // mongoose
db.collection.createIndex({ '$**': 'text' }) // mongoClient
```

You can "smoke" this https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/#std-label-index-feature-text

Need to set option on start mongod like below

```
mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```